# How to build a power supply dc 4.5kv

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power

What would be the simplest way to take A/C line 120 volt  60hz and step it up to 4.5 kv dc output. Would a voltage doubler circuit work for this?

Could this [Neon sign transformer](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-000-volts-3kV-NEON-SIGN-TRANSFORMER-POWER-SUPPLY-/371465254278?hash=item567d0df586:m:mK518wl3AbgWNu8_Hama_jg) be used to get the 1st 3kv and another circuit to raise it to 4.5kv? The purpose of the power supply is to charge a capacitor bank to 4.5kv to exploded a bridge wire. Yes I know this will kill me if I get shocked by it.

Comment: What output current do you want? I know it is probably small (based on your previous question), but think of a number nonetheless. Also, I hope you read the "WARNING!" for that ebay Neon "transformer" (actually an SST).

Comment: 'voltage doubler'? 120 to 4500 is a bit more than double!

Answer (score 1):

High Voltages can be daunting .If your currents are low which I think they are then high order voltage multiplication is possible at sensible switchmode frequencies with practical cap values .Remember that most colledges taught voltage doublers and triplers .From a theory viewpoint any higher order is possible .I would look at a sensible voltage like 500V and pump by 9 to get 4500V .Now your fast diodes and caps and mosfets will be cheap and easy .I have run a Zvs royer into a diode pump with good results .Also I have done a  S trap  boost that works fine .Many other topologies could work if you prefer to stay on familiar ground but the key is that the diode pump is simple especialy if you already have something that works at a fraction of 4500V .

Answer (score 0):

This probably can't give you much sustained current, but if you are charging up capacitors, how about one of these?

[Cockroft-Walton Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator)

Came across it a few weeks ago and looks like it should be relatively easy to make and will just be able to take the 120V AC straight in.

Cheers,
Rob